# display all documents from a collection react firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I have a collection named "journee", and i want to build a list with all elements inside so i get all the data like this :

```
export async function getAllJournaux() {
    const journaux = {};
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "journaux"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        journaux[doc.id] = doc.data();
    });
    return journaux;
}
```

Then on my page getIt witn an useEffect like :

const [journaux, setJournaux] = React.useState();

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getJournaux = async () => {
        try {
            const getJournaux = await getAllJournaux();
            setJournaux(getJournaux);
        } catch(error) {
            // handle any rejections/errors/etc
        }
    };
    getJournaux(); // <-- fetch/compute coupeur value
}, []);
if (!journaux){
    console.log("wait"); // or loading indicator/etc
}else{
    console.log(journaux);
}
```

But how to make a list with the data on my screen , for the moment i just access it with console.log.

The outpout of console.log

```
{
    "8SlEz4CslmTMSxWuqB8W2lDICwj22022-05-02": {
        "date": "2022-05-02",
        "billetage": {
            "5": 0,
            "10": 0,
            "25": 0,
            "50": 0,
            "100": 0,
            "200": 0,
            "250": 0,
            "500": 0,
            "1000": "2",
            "2000": "3",
            "5000": "4",
            "10000": "5"
        },
        "pt": "3400000",
        "at": "30000",
        "vt": "450000",
        "coupeur": "qKh2entwU7YD0wcxWRI3"
    },
    "8SlEz4CslmTMSxWuqB8W2lDICwj22022-05-03": {
        "at": "555",
        "date": "2022-05-03",
        "coupeur": "YuYRYzWj4CVidsmAjO1d",
        "vt": "334",
        "pt": "5555"
    },
    "KiuU1xQaKWTAx5mt9XL8vBpY3Y822022-03-01": {
        "pt": "150000",
        "vt": "450000",
        "date": "2022-03-01",
        "at": "3000",
        "billetage": {
            "5": "5",
            "10": "3",
            "25": "5",
            "50": "1",
            "100": "2",
            "200": "4",
            "250": "2",
            "500": "3",
            "1000": "6",
            "2000": "3",
            "5000": "4",
            "10000": "2"
        },
        "coupeur": "Ad5g5AE2HdqbZGzhu7G5"
    },
    "KiuU1xQaKWTAx5mt9XL8vBpY3Y822022-05-11": {
        "coupeur": "qKh2entwU7YD0wcxWRI3",
        "billetage": {
            "5": 0,
            "10": 0,
            "25": 0,
            "50": 0,
            "100": 0,
            "200": 0,
            "250": 0,
            "500": 0,
            "1000": 0,
            "2000": "5",
            "5000": "3",
            "10000": "10"
        },
        "pt": "30000",
        "date": "2022-05-11",
        "at": "100",
        "vt": "200000"
    },
    "KiuU1xQaKWTAx5mt9XL8vBpY3Y822022-05-23T14:03": {
        "date": "2022-05-23T14:03",
        "pt": "50000",
        "coupeur": "",
        "at": "130000",
        "vt": "200000",
        "billetage": {
            "5": 0,
            "10": 0,
            "25": 0,
            "50": 0,
            "100": 0,
            "200": 0,
            "250": 0,
            "500": 0,
            "1000": 0,
            "2000": "3",
            "5000": "5",
            "10000": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: use your browser dev tools to inspect the response object, expand it to see how it's structured, then you can use your javascript to iterate over the contents. If the contents are empty, then you know your fetch is not properly working.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston , let me add what the console.log outpout cause i dont know how to iterate on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getAllJournaux is returning an object, so you have to use Object.keys to iterate

```
const Component = () => {
  const [journaux, setJournaux] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const getJournaux = async () => {
      try {
        const getJournaux = await getAllJournaux();
        setJournaux(getJournaux);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    getJournaux();
  }, []);
  
  return <ul>
      {Object.keys(journaux || {}).map(item => (
          <li>{item.coupeur}</li>
      ))}
  </ul>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Component = () => {
  const [journaux, setJournaux] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const getJournaux = async () => {
      try {
        const getJournaux = await getAllJournaux();
        setJournaux(getJournaux);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    getJournaux();
  }, []);
  
  // Change .prop1 to a property found in each object of the list
  return <ul>
      {(journaux || []).map(item => (
          <li>{item.prop1}</li>
      ))}
  </ul>
};
```

Comment: thank for your help , but i got this error when i try to map  : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: That happens  when React renders the component before journaux exists. I've edited my answer to default journaux to an empty array.

Comment: i get this after update : Uncaught TypeError: (journaux || []).map is not a function